# Highcharts exporting error?

Tags: highcharts

I've just upgraded my site to the new 3.0 release.

The charts shown on my site are 990x548 pixels.

But when I select an export, regardless of whether it's png/jpg/pdf/svg, the output is 1020x930pixels.

Is this a known bug, or might I be doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have an explicit width set on the chartContainer div.  I was just letting it flow to 100% of the parent element.  As soon as I set an explicit width on that div, the exporting size options worked.  Before that the chart would come out squished regardless of what documented options I set.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can define width / height exported image by chartOptions parameter.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions

Answer (score 0):

the exportButton and printButton are now removed, and replaced with a generic contextButton. So you can use that one for your dropdown menu: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.

See also the new article at http://docs.highcharts.com/#export-module

Please refer my question

[Highcharts 3.0 version changes in exporting options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609088/highcharts-3-0-version-changes-in-exporting-options/15611205#15611205)