# Highcharts 3.0 version changes in exporting options?

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I am glad that highcharts has released an updated 3.0 version

```
http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/54-highcharts-3-0-released
```

and fixed many bugs in highcharts 3.0 but i am confused with highhcharts exporting options now which I had worked on earlier and were working till last week.

This was my working fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/jZ9zV/
```

as people familiar with highcharts will be aware of earlier exporting options .

What has happened is

1. I was only allowing the option to download images and title was only visible in exported images.
2. I don't want to show other default options.
3. How to configure export options like I used to do with chart title images like I used to do earlier please refer my fiddle.
4. The old print button place is coming undefined or some time the logic for export chart loads in that button seems buggy with my export chart code..

Has anyone solved or help me solve my questions?

Thanks - help appreciated :)

Well please see my current workaround below has anyone got it working with 3.0 ?

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking on their support forum directly since this is a very specific component.

Comment: i have mailed to the support team and awating there reply but as i am trying it seems my settings done for version 2.3.5 doesnt work on 3.0 as i want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you'll see from http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons, the exportButton and printButton are now removed, and replaced with a generic contextButton. So you can use that one for your dropdown menu: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.

See also the new article at http://docs.highcharts.com/#export-module

Edit: here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/jZ9zV/5/

```
exporting: {
         filename: 'sfasfasfa',
         buttons: {
             contextButton: {
                 menuItems: [{
                     text: 'Export Chart',
                     onclick: function () {
                         this.exportChart({}, {
                            title: {
                                text: 'sfasfasfa',
                                  style: {
                                        width: '450px'
                                    }
                            }
                        });
                     }
                 }]
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. now i am clear about highcharts new exporting options :)

Comment: Any reason for the blank button that is showing up in your fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what i temporirly to fix the bug on my highcharts export options but i would like to work with 3.0 .

i loaded old version from code.highcharts and commented for now the latest build .

```
<!--
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
-->
<!--
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
-->
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/2.3.5/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/2.3.5/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Updated fiddle with old version

```
jsfiddle.net/jZ9zV/4/ (working)
```

Can any one show me the same functionality with version 3.0

Comment: well i would like some one to tell me how to configure export option like we did in old version 2.3.5 as same in new version 3.0. i dont see the highcharts documentation updated for now.  this fiddle seems helpfull but not compatible with my code right now http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/FX5yy/ .